# When are Django model objects initialized?

Tags: python, django, model, integer, init

I'm facing an interesting problem in Python with Django.
I think just by putting my code you will get what I'm trying to do.

views.py:

```
def ingredients(request):
    objects = Ingredient.objects.all()[:50]
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'objects': objects}
```

models.py:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    stock_by = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    unit = ""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        unit_type = {
            1: 'Units',
            2: 'Kilograms',
            3: 'Litters'
        }
        self.unit = unit_type[IntegerField.to_python(self.cost_by)]
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /Ingredient/
to_python() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

(Value is None).

**init**.py (Django framework class):

```
class IntegerField(field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        try:
            return int(value)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid'],
                code='invalid',
                params={'value': value},
        )
```

I think it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. Just a String attribute which will take the name of the unit value (represented by integers in db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_python` is an instance method you have to call it from the instance, not the class.

```
IntegerField().to_python(self.cost_by)
```